# MySQL User Defined Functions in C++

Tags: c++, mysql-udf

I am trying to run MySQL UDF written in C++. It compiles fine and generates the correct output, but it generates a lot of junk after the output. I would like to know the reason for this junk and how I can resolve this problem? I have attached my code and a screenshot of the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include "mysql-connector-c-6.1.9-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/include/mysql.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/sqlstring.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/datatype.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/resultset_metadata.h"
#include "mysql-connector-c++-1.1.8-linux-ubuntu16.04-x86-64bit/include/cppconn/exception.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    char *hello_world (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,char *result, unsigned long length,char *is_null, char *error);
    my_bool hello_world_init (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
    void hello_world_deinit (UDF_INIT *initid);
    //template <typename T>  T adder (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_eARGS *args,string result, unsigned long length,string is_null, string error,T v);
}

char *hello_world (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *result, unsigned long length, char *is_null, char *error)
{
    string res;
    res = args->args[0];
    res.append(" hello");
    char *c = new char[res.size()];
    strcpy(c, res.c_str());
    return c;
}

my_bool hello_world_init (UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message)
{
    return 0;
    //cout<<"success"<<endl;
}

void hello_world_deinit (UDF_INIT *initid)
{
    return;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu4s0.png)

Comment: The array you allocate as result is too small. You need to add one char for the terminating zero: `new char[res.size() + 1]`.

Comment: The buffer you allocate for the result will cause a memory leak.
You need to manage the memory in the `xxx_init` and `xxx_deinit` functions: pre-allocate a buffer to store the result and free it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the `hello_world` function is wrong. The fourth parameter should be

```
unsigned long *length
```

The value pointed to by that pointer has to be set to the length of the returned string.

```
char *c = new char[res.size() + 1];
strcpy(c, res.c_str());
*length = res.size();
return c;
```